# Why does an eager-loading lazy-loader throw an error?

Tags: c#, exception, lazy-loading

We've got the following code, where, unless we force the lazy-loader to stop being lazy, it'll throw an

> System.MissingMemberException: 'The lazily-initialized type does not have a public, parameterless constructor.'

exception. At least, for the case where we already have the value and we're just making the lazy-loader regurgitate it.

My question is - why? Why is this happening, and what can I do so that we don't need to include `var _ = _lazyChild.Value;`?

```
public class MyContainedClass
{
    private readonly int _id;

    public MyContainedClass(int id) => _id = id;
}

public class MyContainer
{
    private readonly Lazy<MyContainedClass> _lazyChild;

    public MyContainer(MyRepository repo, int? childId, MyContainedClass child = null)
    {
        ChildId = childId;
        if (childId != null)
        {
            _lazyChild = new Lazy<MyContainedClass>(() => child);
            //Without the below line, later accessing _lazyAnswerGroup will throw:
            //System.MissingMemberException: 'The lazily-initialized type does not have a public, parameterless constructor.'
            var _ = _lazyChild.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            _lazyChild = new Lazy<MyContainedClass>(() => ChildId.HasValue ? repo.Get(ChildId.Value) : null);
        };
    }

    public int? ChildId { get; set; }

    public MyContainedClass Child => _lazyChild.Value;
}
```

Sidenote - yes I'm aware there's a bug where you pass in an child element and then later change the ChildId. I'm assuming that's unrelated.

Comment: Can you give a runnable [mre] that reliably reproduces this error? It should be "impossible" to trigger without a very interesting thread race (basically, accessing `_lazyChild` somehow before the constructor has completely run), since it should essentially only happen if the constructor of `Lazy` doesn't get a chance to initialize the value factory member.

Comment: I tried. I can replicate the issue in our 100,000+ LoC legacy app, but I haven't been able to figure out what the actual root cause is to be able to make a MRE. Whenever I've tried, the error doesn't show up.
The weird part is that it's a desktop app with `[STAThread]`, so it should be single-threaded.

Comment: Well, not really -- the main thread being `[STAThread]` doesn't say much of anything about thread use, save for the fact that apparently it kept the defaults from the template. `[STAThread]` matters only to COM clients (which include some GUI components); you are still perfectly free to spawn as many threads as you want. Of course if the project doesn't even mention `Thread` or `BackgroundWorker` anywhere you can be pretty sure there's no more than one thread going on. The other possible causes could include some kind of memory corruption, if you're calling out to "interesting" components.

Comment: Pretty sure it's the reflection we're using, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.
We're also calling a method that uses reflection to make a deep-copy of the object in memory.
Obviously, that isn't going to call the non-parameterless constructor, and therefore the `Lazy<>`s aren't being initialized correctly.